# Correctly calling functions to paint rectangles Python + Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am very new to Python and you will probably believe I should take some lessons, but I have a little trouble that think is caused by my expectations on how Pyhton works and how actually does work.

I have a Raspberry Pi4 receiving a set of coordinates from an Arduino board running some code to deliver a set of x and w coordinates. The RPi4 is processing the information received through the serial port and convert it back to coordinates.

I have used Tkinter on Python to run the GUI (basically 4 buttons image in the background) and plan to draw a rectangle on top of the buttons if the coordinates received are within the range of the button area.

The problems comes here, where I have coded (perpetrated) a script that pretends to draw a rectangle inside a function that is called in the "if" statement where I compare the coordinates. The script throws out an error: _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"

This is my code:

```
from serial import *
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk() 
root.geometry("1280x800")
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
bg = PhotoImage(file = "/home/pi/Pictures/SCREEN2.png") 

canvas = Canvas( root, width = 1280, height = 800) 
canvas.pack(fill = "both", expand = True) 
canvas.create_image( 0, 0, image = bg, anchor = "nw") 
    
serialPort = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser = Serial(serialPort, 9600, timeout=0)
ser.flush()

def split_coords(astring):
    a, b = astring.split(';')
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    
    return (a, b)

def paintRectangle1():
    canvas.create_rectangle(200, 120, 400, 220, fill='red')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    
def paintRectangle2():
    canvas.create_rectangle(600, 120, 800, 220, fill='red')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    
def paintRectangle3():
    canvas.create_rectangle(200, 260, 400, 360, fill='red')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    
def paintRectangle4():
    canvas.create_rectangle(600, 260, 800, 360, fill='red')
    time.sleep(0.3)

root.mainloop() 

while True:
        
    if ser.in_waiting> 0:
        line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
        x, y = split_coords(line)
        print("x:", x, "- y:", y)
        
        if (x>19) and (x<60) and (y>20) and (y<40):
            print("OK button1")
            paintRectangle1()
        if (x>68) and (x<110) and (y>20) and (y<40):
            print("OK button2")
            paintRectangle2()
        if (x>19) and (x<60) and (y>45) and (y<80):
            print("OK button3")
            paintRectangle3()
        if (x>68) and (x<110) and (y>45) and (y<80):
            print("OK button4")
            paintRectangle4()
            
        #else:
            #paint the backgrand image again after the 0.3 seconds defined into the paintRectangle function
```

As you can see I haven't even tried to refresh the background image after a rectangle has been painted as I clearly do not paint a rectangle correctly...

The entire error is as follows:

```
x: 32 - y: 28
OK button1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Touch-GUI-TKInter_4.py", line 52, in <module>
    paintRectangle1()
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Touch-GUI-TKInter_4.py", line 26, in paintRectangle1
    canvas.create_rectangle(200, 120, 400, 220, fill='red')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2501, in create_rectangle
    return self._create('rectangle', args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2480, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

As it can be seen the code correctly interprets the x and y values and prints Ok Button1, which means only the paint function is failing...

If anyone could tell me how donkey I am and point me in the right direction I would be so thankful (and return some dignity to the donkeys).

Thank you in advance.

Happy holidays and new year!

Joan.

Comment: Putting `root.mainloop()` before your `while True:` seems suspicious to me. `root.mainloop` is a blocking operation, which means that the rest of your code won't execute until your call to `root.mainloop()` finishes. So, by the time you reach the body of your while loop, you won't have a valid Tkinter context anymore. At least that's my theory. Try this fix: Remove the line `root.mainloop()`, and in the body of your while loop (adjacent to the if, not inside the if), add first this line: `root.update_idletasks()` and then the line: `root.update()`.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your answer! I have tried that and it actually paints the rectangle but when I stop the process I can see an error in the monitor: _< tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command: application has been destroyed > Man it looks bad...

Comment: Well, I suppose you could wrap those two lines in a try-catch block, but really the correct solution would involve creating a seperate thread and using the `root.mainloop()`. The tkinter `mainloop` blocks, and doing a serial read blocks as well - however, the GUI needs to update irrespective of whether or not the serial read is blocking. Creating a seperate serial reading thread would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet:

```
import turtle

def draw_a_rectangle():

  for x in range(4):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)

draw_a_rectangle()
```